# Authorization Issue Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Database Migration Project migrating an on-premises db to Azure SQL Managed Instance. The activity works fine pulling the database backup from the network location on-premises, but when it tries to apply the backup file from Azure Blob storage it says it does not have access to the file.

The Azure storage account has a storage endpoint, but I noticed that the storage account is not in the same resource group as my Managed Instance. Does that matter at all? Also is there a way to look at the logs for that authorization failure in the Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Resource groups really have nothing to do with how storage (or databases, or any other Azure services) work; they're just organizational boundaries, as well as security boundaries for what operations people can perform on them (moving/deleting/etc).

Comment: Did you set the access control/firewall of the Azure Blob storage?

Comment: Hi, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have set the role permission to access the Azure Storage:
[image]

Add role assignment:

1. **Role:** choose the role (such as 'Contributor')
2. **Assign access to:** Azure AD users, group, or service princpal
3. **Select:** choose your Azure AD users, group, or service princpal.

[image]

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal